# Trying to get latest sugar 2.1.1 version to mint with candy machine ui v3

Tags: web3.js, nft, solana-wallet-adapter, mint, sugar

[image: telling me to use mintv2 instead]

The candy machine was created using token standard : pnft and guard groups, when minting using the latest sugar alpha version , I can mint from a ui like https://github.com/Solana-Studio/Candy-Machine-V3-UI but when minting from sugar 2.1.1 getting an invalid account version error when minting. I don't believe you can mint pnfts with the latest sugar alpha version so wondering if something is missing from the front end code that need to be sent to the sugar 2.1.1 candy machine for it to use mintV2

config sugar 2.1.1
[image: config sugar 2.1.1]

config sugar alpha
[image: config latest sugar alpha]

Comment: Please transcribe the error messages and terminal lines so that the _text_ material to your question can be searched (ie. by Google and the on-site search). You will likely get more engagement if you do.